# Powershell Get-ADOrganizationalUnit Regex

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

Can someone explain how I get the syntax right in the **Get-ADOrganizationalUnit** cmdlet to work in matching an OU name using regular expression?

```
$targetPath = "OU=Some OU, DC=some.domain"

# Capture date in yyyymmdd format and I checked it is .Net valid 
$regex = [regex] "^((20\d{2}))((0?[1-9]|1[012]))(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"

# I need the correct syntax to use below cmdlet
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $targetPath`
    -Filter {(Name -match $regex)}
```

Results in:
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit : Error parsing query: '(Name -match $regex)' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -match' at position: '7'

Yet doing this is a success, so the regex is good

```
$regex.Match("20151112")
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: the operator (`-match` in this case) is not supported. In other words, you cannot use a regex match in a filter for that cmdlet. Try `-like` or get more results and filter them when they return.

Comment: Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $targetPath`
        -Filter {(Name -like $regex)} is syntactically correct but returns no results even though doing -Filter {Name -like "2015*"} shows what should be qualifying matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Filter` in `ActiveDirectory`-cmdlets only supports a subset of operators and `-match` isn't one of them. Rule of thumb is that if it can be done in a LDAP-filter, it can be done in `-Filter` using powershell-operators.

> Supported Operators
>       The following table shows frequently used search filter operators.
>
> ```
>                                                  LDAP
> Operator         Description                     Equivalent
> --------------- ------------------------------ ---------------------
> -eq              Equal to. This will             =
>                  not support wild card
>                  search.
> -ne              Not equal to. This will         !x = y
>                  not support wild card
>                  search.
> -approx          Approximately equal to          ~=
> -le              Lexicographically less than     <=
>                  or equal to
> -lt              Lexicographically less than     !x >= y
> -ge              Lexicographically greater       >=
>                  than or equal to
> -gt              Lexicographically greater than  !x <= y
>
> -and             AND                             &
> -or              OR                              |
> -not             NOT                             !
> -bor             Bitwise OR                      :1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=
> -band            Bitwise AND                     :1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=
> -recursivematch  Use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN :1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=
>                  (Note: This control only works
>                   with Windows 2008 and later.)
> -like            Similar to -eq and supports     =
>                  wildcard comparison. The only
>                  wildcard character
>                  supported is: *
> -notlike         Not like. Supports wild         !x = y
>                  card comparison.
> ```

Source: [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx)